# How to use different MKAnnotationView for 2 different MKPointAnnotation on the same MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have 2 `MKPointAnnotation` and i want to display them on map with two different pins(MKAnnotationView having image).

```
// MKPointAnnotation - 1
CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinate;
cordinate.latitude = [_latitudeString doubleValue];
cordinate.longitude = [_longitudeString doubleValue];
MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cordinate.latitude, cordinate.longitude);
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point1];
```

P.S - When i get second `MKPointAnnotation` i needed self zoom on that area.

```
// MKPointAnnotation - 2
CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinate;
cordinate.latitude = [_latStr doubleValue];
cordinate.longitude = [_longStr doubleValue];
MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cordinate.latitude, cordinate.longitude);
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];

//This is my code for MKAnnotationView 

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]){

        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

        if(!pinView){

            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        }
        else{

            pinView.annotation = annotation;   
        }

        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

What i need to change in the `viewForAnnotation` method?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create subclass of `MKPointAnnotation`.

```
@interface SecondAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation
@end

@implementation SecondAnnotation
@end
```

Add `SecondAnnotation` to the mapView.

```
// MKPointAnnotation - 2
...
SecondAnnotation *point2 = [[SecondAnnotation alloc] init];
point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cordinate.latitude, 
cordinate.longitude);
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];
```

You can use different MKAnnotationView with the following code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]){

        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

        if(!pinView){

            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Annotation"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        }
        else{

            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return pinView;
    } else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SecondAnnotation class]]){

        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

        if(!pinView){

            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Second"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        }
        else{

            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

Comment: Well the code didn't gave the expected results. I was still getting the image of 1st MKPointAnnotation at the place of 2nd MKPointAnnotation. But doing some changes solved the problem. Thanks for the help and idea to create another subclass of MKPointAnnotation

Answer (score 0):

Writing the `viewForAnnotation` as below solved my problem -

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{


if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]){

 MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

  if(!pinView){

   pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

   pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
   pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation"];
   pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

  }
  else{

   pinView.annotation = annotation;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SecondAnnotation class]]) {

     pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"range"];

    }
    else{

     pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation"];

    }

  }

  return pinView;

 }

 return nil;


}
```